# IdHTTP in Android service in Delphi RX

Tags: android, delphi, service, indy, idhttp

I try to write an Android service, which will use IdHTTP component to send messages to the server. 
I just put IdHTTP1 on TAndroidServiceDM and try to Run app on Phone (Android 4.2.2) 
I get error:
"**Project LocSensDemo.apk raised exception class Exception with message 'Activity not found, maybe you are in a service'**" 
in FMX.Platform.Android line 1792 "*Activity := TAndroidHelper.Activity;*"
and then 
"**Project LocSensDemo.apk raised exception class Segmentation fault (11)**".
Service crashes.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The `Activity` error has nothing to do with Indy, it is an Embarcadero problem. The `TAndroidHelper.Activity` property does not work in a service. As for the `Segmentation fault` error, you have not provided any details to diagnose that with. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the error.

Comment: Here is a minimal project: App and Service https://mega.nz/#!VdJliLSR!_o2kTZJeMNRwP8lbaazbs4zdsbkXY1vx6gW3wPWspCI

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity not found` exception occurs when the `TAndroidHelper.Activity` property is accessed inside a service project.  That property is not usable in a service (see [RSP-13381](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13381)).  Anything that uses `TAndroidHelper.Activity` in a service will crash at runtime.  Line 1792 in the `FMX.Platform.Android` unit is inside of `FMX.Platform.Android.TWindowManager.RetrieveContentRect()`.  What are you accessing in a service that is using `TWindowManager`?  Services don't have UIs, you should not be touching anything UI-related to begin with.

If your service code needs access to an Android `Context` object, such as to call `getContentResolver()`, you can use the `TAndroidHelper.Context` property, or your service's own `JavaService` property (Android's `Service` class derives from `Context`).

As for the `Segmentation fault` exception, you haven't provided any details about that error, or shown what code is causing it, so there is no way for anyone here to diagnose it for you.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I use only IdHTTP component, northing else. I think the problem is here: then i put IdHTTP to service in 'uses' appears IdComponent unit. Chain using: IdComponent -> IdStack -> FMX.Helpers.Android -> Androidapi.Helpers which give me "Activity not found, maybe you are in a service" exception.

Comment: You said the "Activity not found" error is occurring in the `FMX.Platform.Android` unit on line 1792, which is inside the FMX `TWindowManager` class, which Indy does not use. The error is raised by the `TAndroidHelper.Activity` property, which Indy does not use. You mention `IdStack`, which does use `FMX.Android.Helpers`, but it does not use `TAndroidHelper.Activity`, it uses `TAndroidHelper.Context`, which is safe in a service. Prior to Seattle, `IdStack` does use `SharedActivityContext()`, but that does not raise the error, and pre-Seattle versions do not support Android services anyway.

Comment: Can you debug the Android app/service can get the actual call stack when the error occurs? I need to see the chain of calls that leads up to `TAndroidHelper.Activity` being used.